# Make the code folding icons always show in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Loving using Visual Studio Code but one peeve is that I always think my code isn't indented properly since the left edge of the actual editor is kind of far from the numbers.

Is there any way to show the code folding +/- icons by default? It only shows them if you hover over the gutter.

As an aside, if there is a way to change the color of the gutter so it looks distinct from the editor?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To change the color of the gutter, you can add following to the user settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGutter.background": "#abcdef"
}
```

And to show folding icons:

```
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always"
```

Note that this setting requires you to have at least **1.13**.

Comment: Excellent! glad that this was added.

Comment: This was broken in 1.17 and is slated to be fixed in 1.19 (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35839).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but FWIW:

File > Preferences > Settings

User > Text Editor > Editor: Show Folding Controls

Select "Always"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make code folding icons appear persistently. It is discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2948#issuecomment-186864695) on project github page however it is not implemented yet.

If you want proper indentation your best bet is **indentation guides** (the vertical lines that run down to matching indents).

Indentation guides are not displayed by default.
To enable indent guides go to ***File --> Preferences --> Settings*** and then place following line in settings.json file,

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true
```

[image: Indent Guide VSCode]

Comment: That certainly does help. Hopefully they merge in that requested feature. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can make code folding icons appear persistently by addding :
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
but not in the "workbench.colorCustomizations", just put it outside and it will work.
example:

```
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
    "scrollbarSlider.background": "#474552",
    "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#295377",
},
```

and since the [+][-] icons were replaced with [>][v], you can use this extension to regain this feature: [Minimalist Product Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ElAnandKumar.el-vsc-product-icon-theme)